# No Matching provisioning profile found in Xcode continuous integration (Xcode 7.2)

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode-server

Issue : i have setup a continuous integration with the help of Xcode server but in app when i integrate my bot i got above error.

i have seen a lots of post on this and find out that i need to setup my provisioning profile in `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles` but i am not able to find out this location. please see [image: below image]

[image: Error Image]

also in i have setup my xcode server by following http://useyourloaf.com/blog/continuous-integration-with-xcode-server/ 
link.

i have seen the provisioning profile here and i reset and downloaded them again still no luck.[image: Mobile Provisioning path]

Checked the path but it showing provisioning profile folder in red. why that so ?
[image: Path from hard disk]

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the library path from the hard drive itself and not the individual users library?

Comment: Sorry but i don't know library path form hard drive. can you please tell me where i can find this ?

Comment: Macintosh HD -> Library -> Developer  if you go to your username folder, click on it, and then (command + UP), it will bring you to the Macintosh HD, and you should see the path